# Via Java Validation, is it possible to set a field to null using a custom field level constraint?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have created a field level constraint.  When the value is less than zero I need to return a message and set it to zero.  Possible?  This doesn't seem to work:

```
    @Override
public boolean isValid(Double value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
        ValidationUtils.addEMessage(context, this.getClass(), errorLevel, "odo is null");
        return false;
    }
    if (MAX_ODOMETER.compareTo(value) < 0) {
        ValidationUtils.addEMessage(context, this.getClass(), errorLevel, "odo too big:" + Double.valueOf(value).toString());
        value = null;//  <--- doesn't work!
        return false;
    }
}
```